# Geospatial data quality check and business rules in GeoServer WFS-T

Tags: postgis, geoserver, java, jts-topology-suite

I need to check Geospatial and alpha numeric data quality and check spatial business rules before to update/insert/delete the data.

Actually we have postgis and geoserver deployed and java devloppers available. Triggers in postgis are not allowed.

Is it possible to add this checks in geoserver? or maybe do we need do deploy an independant REST API with JTS?

EDIT: Can GeoFence be used as workaround? i have seen spatial predicate can allow or deny

Comment: One possibility is to capture the WFS transaction request and pass it to your own java code that runs the tests. If they are OK the transaction can be forwarded to GeoServer. Otherwise java code returns some suitable WFS error for the client. There is a route for creating and publishing your code as a GeoServer community module. I suggest to contact the GeoServer developers through geoserver-devel mailing list for the details if that option interests you. Or if your company provides the funding someone else can do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have Java developers on hand I would go with a custom WPS process that takes the input, validates it and then saves it to the underlying datastore (either directly or via WFS). There is a [process tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) which should get you started and the GeoTools users list should be able to help if you have any questions.

There used to be a validation plugin for GeoServer but I think it died a long time ago, but you might be able to resurrect the code to give you more ideas.